# Primefaces dataTable with checkBox problem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

First of all, code:

```
<p:dataTable id="tablePriceCriteria" value="#{kuBean.criteriaList}" selection="#{kuBean.selectedCriteriaList}" var="criteria">

                            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width: 50px;"/>

                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Criteria name" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{criteria.criteriaPK.criteriaName}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Measure unit" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{criteria.measureUnit}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Size" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{criteria.criteriaPK.size}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <p:commandButton value="Add criteria to service" actionListener="#{kuBean.addPricesToService}"
                                                 oncomplete="wiz.next()"/>
                            </f:facet>

                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="Prices" title="Price">
                    <p:panel>
                        <p:dataTable value="#{kuBean.service.pricesList}" var="price">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Usluga: #{kuBean.service.serviceName}
                            </f:facet>

                            <p:column headerText="Criteria name">
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{price.criteria.criteriaPK.criteriaName}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Measure unit">
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{price.criteria.measureUnit}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Size">
                                <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{price.criteria.criteriaPK.size}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Service Price">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{price.price}"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{price.price}" style="width: 100%;"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

When I looked on code I realize that there is no chance anybody to understand anything, so I try to explain what's happening here.

I have tables in database (primary keys are bold):

Service: **serviceID**, serviceName

Criteria: **criteriaName, size**, measureUnit

Price: **serviceID, criteriaName, size**, price

My classes are:

**Service**, that have list of prices, and 
**Criteria**, also have list of prices and criteriaPK that holds criteriaName and size.
**Price** have unique criteria and service. Also have pricePK that have criteriaName, size and serviceID.

I created primefaces wizard, that have attribute widgetVar="wiz". And finally a question. In dataTable are list of all criteria. What I want to do when I check some criteria and click on button "Add criteria to service" is that selected criteria is add to service.

Code of method addPricesToService:

```
    List<Prices> priceList = new LinkedList<Price>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getSelectedCriteriaList().length; i++) {
        Criteria criteria = getSelectedCriteriaList[i];
        Price c = new Price(new PricePK(service.getPriceID(), criteria.getCriteriaPK().getCriteriaName(), criteria.getCriteriaPK().getSize()));
        c.setPrice(0);
        priceList.add(c);
    }
    service.setPriceList(priceList);
```

What I get is just an exception:

```
SEVERE: Received 'java.lang.NullPointerException' when invoking action listener '#{kuBean.dodajCeneUsluzi}' for component 'j_idt46'
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at util.ServiceCreatingManager.addPricesToService(ServiceCreatingManager.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:912)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:943)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 : UIComponent-ClientId=formaKreiranjeUsluge:tabelaKriterijuma, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:912)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:943)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at util.ServiceCreatingManager.addPricesToService(ServiceCreatingManager.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
        ... 34 more
```

It's obviously that nothing is selected and that's why nullPointerException is thrown. Any help?
p.s. If something is hard to understand I shall explain more.

Comment: It surprises me to see that the action listener is executed during apply request values phase instead of invoke action phase. Don't you *actually* have an `immediate="true"` put on the button? I couldn't find it in your view example. But having an `immediate="true"` on the button would at least explain why the model is not been updated with selected values at the point the action is invoked.

Comment: Yes I have `immediate="true"` on button, but exception happens with or without it.

Comment: @BalusC
everything is actually very easy. I want dataTable with checkBox column and button, which when I press and call some method can access selected (checked) items.

Comment: It should at least not be `immediate="true"`. Is the bean in request or view scope? How do you prepare the list for the table?

Comment: It is session scope bean. Interesting thing is that, when I try to do case like in the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf), where I add dialog and dataList in that dialog filled with list of selected criteria and set update attribute of button to update dialog - everything is just fine. Dialog with list of selected criteria comes up.

Comment: @Bojan, Are you expecting that selecting the check box will select the row of the dataTable?  You would be wrong to think this.  The row of the dataTable is considered selected when it is highlighted  Your dataTable doesn't seem to have any selected rows.

Comment: Because you just call js, if you try to call backing bean it will not fire...I still look answer

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{kuBean.service.pricesList}" var="price">
```

It seems from your code extract, that pricesList is a List.

```
List<Prices> priceList = new LinkedList<Price>();
...
service.setPriceList(priceList);
```

All you have to do is change priceList in service from a "List priceList" object to an array object e.g. "Price[] priceList".